# How to create complex where clause using MyBatis Generator Example class?

Tags: sql, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I want to create a where criteria like this: "A and B and (C or D)".
But I don't know how to create it using MyBatis Generator Example class.
I can do it when I change the where clause to "(A and B and C) or (A and B and D)", but I think the above one is better.
MyBatis Generator document: http://mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/exampleClassUsage.html.

Answer (score 0):

In Complex Queries part of Mybatis Doc,its example is similar with your problam.

Comment: Actually it's not what I need. The example is "(A and B and C) or (A and B and D)", but what I need is "A and B and (C or D)" in which "or" is in the parentheses.

Comment: Tried a time,then looked created xml file and created 'Example' object. I finded it only use 'and' in the parentheses .You can look <sql id="Example_Where_Clause" > that it create in xml.

Comment: This is a well known limitation of the 'Example' object in the legacy runtime. If you can switch to the new "Mybatis3DynamicSQL" runtime then you can write the where clause as you desire.